# regex groups: How to get the desired output with a more specific match pattern?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The following input list of entries

```py
l = ["555-8396 Neu, Allison", 
     "Burns, C. Montgomery", 
     "555-5299 Putz, Lionel",
     "555-7334 Simpson, Homer Jay"]
```

is expected to be transformed to:

```
Allison Neu 555-8396
C. Montgomery Burns  
Lionel Putz 555-5299 
Homer Jay Simpson 555-7334
```

I tried the following:

```py
for i in l:
    mo = re.search(r"([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)", i)
    if mo:
        print("{} {} {}".format(mo.group(3), mo.group(2), mo.group(1)))
```

and it results in the following incorrect output (note the "None" in the second line of output)

```
Allison Neu 555-8396
C. Montgomery Burns None
Lionel Putz 555-5299
Homer Jay Simpson 555-7334
```

However the following solution mentioned in the [e-book](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_re.php) does indeed give the desired output:

```py
for i in l:
    mo = re.search(r"([0-9-]*)\s*([A-Za-z]+),\s+(.*)", i)
    print(mo.group(3) + " " + mo.group(2) + " " + mo.group(1))
```

In short, it boils down to the difference in the groups() output of the 2 reg exp searches:

```py
>>> mo = re.search(r"([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)", "Burns, C. Montgomery")
>>> mo.groups()
(None, 'Burns', 'C. Montgomery')
```

versus

```py
>>> mo = re.search(r"([0-9-]*)\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)", "Burns, C. Montgomery")
>>> mo.groups()
('', 'Burns', 'C. Montgomery')
```

None vs ''

I wanted to do a **more accurate match** of the phone number format with [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4} instead of using [0-9-]* which can match arbitrary number and - combinations (ex: "0-1-2" or "1-23").

Why does "*" result in a different grouping than "?".
Yes, it is trivial for me to take care of the "None" while printing out the result, but I am interested to know the reason for the difference in grouping results.

Comment: Why are you trying this using regexp if your first regexp is right on the money? If there is no regexp match then `None` seems to be perfect for the job. Just filter that one out using e.g. an `if` statement when it comes to printing out the results...

Comment: True @Maarten-reinstateMonica, it is trivial to take care of None when printing the output. But the real question that I had was: why the difference in the results of grouping ? I didnt understand that.

Comment: I guess the given answer does explain that well, if you have `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?` then the question mark means that the entire group is optional, and in the case of Monty it's indeed not there. Just like it should be, much better than accepting any kind of digits and `-` signs in any order.

Comment: Is it just a case of fixing the regex given, or is a better one needed?

Comment: My question was to understand the behavior and the selected answer did exactly that. Also, fixes to the regex were also given which was very useful too. If there is a better one, am definitely interested to know it as well.

Comment: Ok, this regex `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)` can be fixed so _`none`_ is not stringified, by putting non-capture groups around it and making that optional, like this `((?:[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?)\s*(\w*)\s*,\s*(\S.*)` It sure sounded like it was a better regex that was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me say in plain English what RegEx demos are hinting at and actually answer your actual question:

1. `([0-9-]*)` Matches 0 or more characters of digits or the `-` character. When there is no telephone present, that would be the case of *matching* 0 characters. But note the operative word *matching*, i.e. it is still a match. Thus, `mo.group(1)` returns `''`.
2. `([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?` Attempts to match a phone number in a specific format, but this match is *optional*. When the phone number is not present in the input, the match *does not exist* and thus `mo.group(1)` returns `None`.

Answer (score 3):

```
((?:[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?)\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Qx6ylw/1

In the book example `group` was not optional...its contents were....in your regex `group` was optional.

Answer (score 1):

Using judicious whitespace trimming, a simple find and replace example is this :

Find: `^((?:\d+(?:-\d+)+)?)\s*([^,]*?)\s*,\s*(.*)`
Replace `\3 \2 \1`

https://regex101.com/r/oo0NWy/1

Answer (score 0):

This code solves your problem:

```
for i in l:
    mo = re.search(r"([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})?\s*(\w*),\s*(\S.*$)", i)
    if mo:
        if mo.group(1):
            print("{} {} {}".format(mo.group(3), mo.group(2), mo.group(1)))
        else:
            print("{} {}".format(mo.group(3), mo.group(2)))
```

Output:

```
Allison Neu 555-8396
C. Montgomery Burns
Lionel Putz 555-5299
Homer Jay Simpson 555-7334
```